# SQL Server Isnull Devuelve 1900-01-01 cuando el campo es nulo

Tags: sql, sql-server

El siguiente código devuelve 1900-01-01 cuando el campo Fecha ​​es nulo asignando cadena ('').
El resultado deseado es si al ser campo null diga 'Disponible'.

Nota:  Se esta generando una vista

. ¿Cómo debo proceder para obtener los resultados deseados?, es posible por ser de tipo date?

```
MIN(CASE WHEN orden = 1 THEN Fecha ELSE ISNULL(Fecha,'Disponible') END  ) AS 'Fecha 1',
```

Saludos comunidad!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(25), ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(10), Fecha, 126), ' '))Fecha
```

Y en la parte donde genera el null:

```
MIN(CASE WHEN orden = 1 THEN  Fecha ELSE 'Disponible' END  ) AS 'Fecha 1',
```

Solucionado:
"En este caso que volcarás los valores de la consulta a un archivo de texto con columnas de tamaño fijo es correcto realizar el formateo de las columnas sobre la consulta, en cualquier otro caso la base de datos retorna dato y la UI formatea los valores. Sobre la recomendación no olvides castear a un tipo CHAR(n) para lograr el ancho fijo y el estilo a tomar es el 126 -según te sugiere también AMB-"